# pulseaudio is duplicating an airplay target

Tags: pulseaudio

Not a big issue, but pulseaudio is recognizing an Airplay target as 2 separate output devices (ip address is same).

`pacmd list-sinks | grep name:` shows like this

```
name: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.hdmi-stereo

name: raop_output.iPhone.local

name: raop_output.iPhone.local.2
```

(Ubutu 17.10 and pulseaudio 10 with raop / Ubuntu 18.04 and pulseaudio 11.1)

Comment: So what is your question?  What do you want?

Comment: I want to merge them.

Comment: Got the same issue and none seem to be working